# How to get the exact encoding time using compiled ffmpeg library

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, raspberry-pi4

I have configured and compiled the ffmpeg source to enable hardware-accelerated encoding (h264_omx) on raspberry pi 4B.

Can anyone plz tell me how to get the exact encoding time from the script? **can anyone point out which function or API call inside the ffmpeg code is responsible for hardware-accelerated encoding?**

Comment: Paul - what are you trying to accomplish? Where does your video originate? Camera or file? - What is your output? Streaming or file. What kind of file (MP4 or other) are you creating? May be it is easier to use straight OpenMAX (OMX) instead of going through FFMPEG.

Comment: @Markus- Input is png files and output video is a mp4 file. I encoded using h264_omx encoder on raspberry pi. But how to get the exact time of encoding? If there is an API in FFmpeg I can log time before and after the API call inside the ffmpeg. Can u plz also tell me How can I straight use OpenMax (OMX) in raspberry pi?

Comment: Concerning your timing question - most H.264 encoder work asynchronous and have a certain amount of frames latency. So you push your uncompressed frame into the input queue of the encoder and eventually you can pull the compressed frame out of the output queue. Now getting the exact time it took to compress a particular single frame - may be hard specially if hardware as black box was involved. For OMX I'd look here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_encode/encode.c